# google actions: conversation exit using actions sdk does not invoke actions.intent.CANCEL

Tags: actions-on-google

I am using the actions SDK to build fulfilments. I am using Google Functions for the same. I have the following in the `action.json`

```
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "description": "Default Welcome Intent",
      "name": "MAIN",
      "fulfillment": {
        "conversationName": "App"
      },
      "intent": {
        "name": "actions.intent.MAIN",
        "trigger": {
          "queryPatterns": [
            . . .
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "conversations": {
    "App": {
      "name": " ... ",
      "url": " ...",
      "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
    }
  },
  "locale": "en"
}
```

In the function code I notice that the custom intent code of `actions.intent.CANCEL` is not getting called when the user says/ types `exit` or `Goodbye`. In the emulator only the `<earcon>` appears. The JS code is as below:

```
app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', (conv) => {
  conv.ask('Welcome to ...');
});

app.intent('actions.intent.TEXT', (conv, input) => {
  // the main logic of the application is here
  });

app.intent('actions.intent.CANCEL', (conv) => {
  conv.close(`Okay, let's try this again later.`); 
  // this code does not get called
});
```

Is something to be set in action.json for the cancel intent to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to [add something](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/conversation-exits#actions_sdk) to your action.json for it to send you the CANCEL Intent. In your existing `conversations` object, add an `inDialogIntents` attribute with an array of objects giving the name of the CANCEL Intent. Something like this:

```
"conversations": {
  "App": {
    "name": "...",
    "url": "...",
    "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
    "inDialogIntents": [
      {
        "name": "actions.intent.CANCEL"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Prisoner. feel stupid that I did not scroll to read the actions sdk part of the conversation exit documentation. If I may ask, I am unable to create custom built intents. All responses from the user seem to be received by `actions.intent.TEXT`.  If I need to create one should those be within `inDialogIntents` too?

Comment: The short answer is no, that's not how you do it, but really that's a different question. I think its been answered before on StackOverflow but, if not, feel free to post a new question.